# Use multiple HttpSessionIdResolver with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to use the HTTPSessionIdResolver for everything located under "/api**" and for everything else the standard CookieResolver.

How is this possible, so that the two configurations use different resolvers? With my current approach everything uses X-AUTH.

I tried to understand the implementation within Spring and I end up in the SessionRepositoryFilter, but of this filter only one instance is created, so der exists only one resolver.

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class TestConfig {

    @EnableSpringHttpSession
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class Abc extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver xAuth() {
            return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public MapSessionRepository mapSessionRepository(){
            return new MapSessionRepository(new HashMap<>());
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/service/json/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
        }

    }

    @EnableSpringHttpSession
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/user/registration", "/webfonts/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
        }

        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
            JdbcUserDetailsManager manager = new UserDetailsManager(dataSource());
            manager.setUsersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from users where username=?");
            manager.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username,authority from authorities where username = ?");
            return manager;
        }

        @Autowired
        public void initialize(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
            builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsManager()).passwordEncoder(bcrypt());
        }
     }
  }
```

I could move the logic into one resolver which delegates the work to the existing resolvers, but this seems hacky?

```
public class SmartHttpSessionIdResolver implements HttpSessionIdResolver {

    private static final String HEADER_X_AUTH_TOKEN = "X-Auth-Token";
    private static final CookieHttpSessionIdResolver cookie = new CookieHttpSessionIdResolver();
    private static final HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver xauth = HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();

    @Override
    public List<String> resolveSessionIds(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (isXAuth(request)) {
            return xauth.resolveSessionIds(request);
        }
        return cookie.resolveSessionIds(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSessionId(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String sessionId) {
        if (isXAuth(request)) {
            xauth.setSessionId(request, response, sessionId);
        } else {
            cookie.setSessionId(request, response, sessionId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void expireSession(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (isXAuth(request)) {
            xauth.expireSession(request, response);
        } else {
            cookie.expireSession(request, response);
        }
    }

    private boolean isXAuth(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader(HEADER_X_AUTH_TOKEN) != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is your original problem that you have tried to solve in this way?

Comment: Why you need to handle /api with one two different Resolvers? If you already use Spring Security, have think about roles, and to solve problem using that approach?  For example http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN").antMatchers("/api").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();  This is just one way. You can also set @RolesAllowed({"USER","ADMIN"}) for every Controller method and on that way control access right of different roles.

Comment: @m4gic: I think my main problem can be guessed from the first sentence, but maybe you are right and this is not clear enough: There are two types of clients which want to get data from my backend. For the first group (e.g. browsers which do the handling of cookies for me), if want to use cookies. And for the second group (e.g. an android app) I want to use an additional auth header and no cookies so I can turn of the CSRF protection via tokens.

Comment: @mommcilo: See my clarification.

Comment: I  would use both approach: from the backend perspective, the key point is that your user has to authenticate his/herself in any way. So instead of trying to separate these kind of requests, you should enable them to authenticate themselves in any way, if they contains cookies, you should serve them, similarly, if they have an auth header, you should serve them too. E.g. in WebLogic, there is a similar mechanism, where the JAAS login modules were sufficient, that means that ANY of them authenticated the user, the request can be served, otherwise obviously not.

Comment: So what I would like to recommend is the usage of multiple authentication providers, which is not rare for this kind of use cases.

Comment: I think this solution was nice! I have been working on this the whole day and this is the first solution that works.. I have different authentications for different parts of the app and I want users to be able to be logged in to both of these at the same time without having to reauthenticate when switching realm (but also be able to be logged in to just one of them). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attempting the solution provided in the question (which works fine, to be honest), I also attempted to do this by providing two different filters. However, when `@EnableSpringHttpSession` is added, a `SessionRepositoryFilter` is added automatically and adding two more of those in the servlet filter chain seems odd. Therefore, I thought they would have to go in the security filter chain instead, which is good because then we can use the URL matching made there as well (instead of having to implement that elsewhere as well).

Since other security filters use the `HttpSession`, we have to manually place the `SessionRepositoryFilter` first in this chain. This is what I came up with (in Kotlin) which works well for me:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig() {

    private val sessionStore = ConcurrentHashMap<String, Session>()
    private val sessionRepo = MapSessionRepository(sessionStore)

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    inner class XAuthConfig(): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

        override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
            http
                .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/api**")
                    .and()
                .addFilterBefore(
                    SessionRepositoryFilter(sessionRepo).apply{
                        setHttpSessionIdResolver(
                            HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
                        )
                    }, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter::class.java)
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    inner class DefaultConfig(): WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

        override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
            http
                .addFilterBefore(
                    SessionRepositoryFilter(sessionRepo).apply{
                        setHttpSessionIdResolver(
                            CookieHttpSessionIdResolver()
                        )
                    }, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter::class.java)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Note** that the annotation `@EnableSpringHttpSession` has been removed. Instead, we add the `SessionRepositoryFilter`s manually before the `WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter`s (the first filter in the security filter chain). The function of the `SessionRepositoryFilter` is to replace the existing `HttpSession` with Spring's `HttpSession` which it will do no matter if we place it manually or if it's put in place automatically by means of autoconfiguration. As long as no other filter before the security filter chain makes use of the session, this should work out. Otherwise, some filter rearrangement might still do the trick.

Comment: Sorry for the later answer. That is the solution I was searching for. Works perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As you mention above, based on the code of "[SessionRepositoryFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.java)" class, it is clear that it supports only a single "HttpSessionIdResolver". As a result, if you use only one "SessionRepositoryFilter", your only option seems to be the one that you suggested. Although this would work, it does feel a bit hacky and also, if your requirement is indeed to use the "HTTPSessionIdResolver" for everything located under "/api**", then it doesn't ensure that.

Since "SessionRepositoryFilter" class is effectivelly a Filter, I suggest checking if you could create two Spring beans for the "SessionRepositoryFilter" class. One that will be used for all HTTP endpoints under the "/api*" pattern and another for all other paths. Then, you could use the "HttpSessionIdResolver" and "CookieSessionIdResolver" respectivelly. You can find an example for defining different filters based on URL patterns [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter).

Comment: I could add a check for the requested URL prefix than the according auth mechanism would be ensured. But thats also not nice. Is their no way to define this in the separated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter? These are two separated filter chains so I would expect to easily provide different session resolvers.

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work by creating a subclass of RedisHttpSessionConfiguration. Then you will have available a filter called `springHeaderSessionRepositoryFilter` which you can use to configure another filter with a different `filter-mapping` in your web app.

```
public class MyCustomRedisHttpSessionConfiguration extends RedisHttpSessionConfiguration {

      @Bean
      public <S extends Session> SessionRepositoryFilter<? extends Session> springHeaderSessionRepositoryFilter(SessionRepository<S> sessionRepository) {
        SessionRepositoryFilter<S> sessionRepositoryFilter = new SessionRepositoryFilter<>(sessionRepository);
        sessionRepositoryFilter.setHttpSessionIdResolver(HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken());
        return sessionRepositoryFilter;
      }
    
}
```